# Bibliography with alphabetical order, year order but without brackets in references part

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am trying to find a bibliography that looks like the one [here](http://icml.cc/2012/papers/625.pdf).
I found [this](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf) but it doesn't have this style and when I try some of
them LaTeX cannot find them. How do I have to add them to my LaTeX and
how should I find the bibliography I mentioned. I tried apa-style which
looks like the one I mentioned but the problem is it also puts brackets
in bibliography part in the main pdf which I don't want them.

Comment: Could you tell us more about what packages you are using? Anything like `biblatex`? Perhaps you could give us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have (TeX file and bibliography file), otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @ienissei, just to clarify I ulready got the answer from David Carlisle, but I was using biblatex, and my bibliography style was apalike.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The lack of more specific information about what you already tried or looked for is probably why your question got closed (which isn't a problem in itself, since you got the answer anyway). We try to encourage questions that point to a specific problem and show what you have done in order to solve it (which is a good way to learn, as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you link to is a conference paper and as is common for such conferences the author instructions have specific LaTeX guidelines.

http://icml.cc/2012/author-instructions/

Links to a zip file that has a bibliography style to be used and an example document.

Comment: I didn't know that. Sorry!